# Is it okay to stay an extra day than my Schengen visa validity if I pass through immigration before midnight?

Tags: schengen, itineraries

I have a Schengen visa valid from 15 August 2017 to 9 September 2017, but my duration of stay is only 10 days.

I'm travelling to Europe from the 15th to 24th of August. I'm getting a ticket for a flight that leaves on the 25th August, for very low price since it departs must after midnight at 00:35 hours.I have to check in airport on the 24th Aug by 10 pm.

With this itinerary, am I going to have any issues at the Consulate?

Comment: When you say "my duration of stay", do you mean the duration of stay that your visa allows, or the actual duration of your stay?

Comment: It's most likely the duration of stay that visa allows.

Comment: I believe someone with a rich experience can better answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

In your opening line you say you have a visa, but then later you ask about issues at the consulate. But basically the same answer applies if you are talking about the immigration official when you land or the consular official when you apply.

Officially your travel period is 11 days since your flight departs after midnight.  But in real life terms you will have cleared immigration and left the country the day before (unless you are really running wayyyy late).  It will lie with the judgement of the official handling your entry/visa application to decide to allow the leeway or apply the letter of the law.

Comment: I think what OP is wrestling with is that he asked for 10 days in the application, got a month, and now thinks that an 11th day might be an issue, one day more because of the return flight departure just after midnight. I tried to be extra careful in my edit, not to misinterpret, but that's what I thought was meant.

Comment: @HenningMakholm you might want to undelete, as I think your understanding is correct. OP asked for 10 days, got a month, leaving on the 11th day, technically, b/c flight is just after midnight.

Comment: @Dorothy - where are you getting a "month" from?  The validity period specified and length of stay are both less than a month.

Comment: Sorry, Tom, meaning the visa was issued with a validity from  15 August to 9 September and OP will be in the Area from 15th until his flight departs on 25 Aug at 00:35. When he counted the days, he realized it was 11, instead of 10.